# Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given

Tags: php, mysqli

```
function f_sqlConnect($user, $pass, $db) {
$link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', $user, $pass);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($db, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . $db . ': ' . mysql_error());
}
}
```

I am getting errors on this and when I remove $link I get another error

Comment: Reverse your arguments. The $link comes first. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php  But in MySQLi, you can pass `$db` as the fourth argument to `mysqli_connect()` so you may as well place it there as `mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', $user, $pass, $db)` and avoid `mysqli_select_db()` entirely.

Comment: Thank you the problem is I am trying to                                        /*Cleans an array to protect against injection attacks.*/
function f_clean($array) {
    return array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $array);
}

/*Connects to and selects the specified database with the specified user.*/
function f_sqlConnect($user, $pass, $db) {
 $link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', $user, $pass);

 if (!$link) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

 $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($db, $link);

 if (!$db_selected) {
  die('Can\'t use ' . $db . ': ' . mysql_error());
 }
}

Comment: You are also mixing `mysql_error()` in the MySQLi API. The two are not compatible. You need to be using `mysqli_connect_error()` for the first one, and  `mysqli_error($link)` for the one after selecting the DB. If you want to continue separating the db selection action, you must _reverse the arguments_ as `mysqli_select_db($link, $db);`

Comment: Thank you Michael I have changed it now  I am getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysqli_connect_error' (T_STRING

Comment: That suggests you did not call it as a function: `die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());`  And after setting the database `die('Can\'t use ' . $db . ': ' . mysqli_error($link));`

Comment: Thank you very much I am pretty new at this I am trying to understand the not call to function.  I apologized  in advance.